# Jackson - What is the best way to model a map of lists in a DTO property where the list keys are flexible and the list may arrive as a single word?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, jackson, dto

I'm working with a REST API which returns a set of objects that contains a flexible "attributes" element which is very loose in how it returns the data. For instance, the API may return a Collection of CharacterProfiles as follows:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "another523somminguid",
        "name": "Stan Smith",
        "attributes": {
            "occupation": "CIA Agent",
            "description": "A very opinionated agent with a very large chin"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "some123abcguid",
        "name": "Roger Smith",
        "attributes": {
            "appearance": [
                "alien",
                "pear-shaped",
                "bulbous head"
            ],
            "abilities": [
                "costume design",
                "super speed"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "299anotherguid",
        "name": "Steve Smith",
        "attributes": {
            "appearance": [
                "bespectacled",
                "skinny",
                "brown hair"
            ],
            "abilities": "no notable abilities"
        }
    }
]
```

Seeing that the `attributes` property takes a rather loose form where it is not really possible to know *all* of the keys in advance, only really knowing they are strings, I elected to build the DTO to accept a Map of Lists as follows:

```java
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public @Data @Builder class CharacterProfile {
    String id;
    String name;
    // How do I specify this format to accept the wide variety of JSON objects?
    @JsonFormat(with = what_feature?)
    Map<String, Collection<String>> attributes;
}
```

My picking through the Jackson JavaDocs for the [`@JsonFormat`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Feature.html) annotation tells me that using the [`JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Feature.html) feature might work, but every reference suggests this only works for objects which implement the `Collection` interface.

Do I need to rethink my design? Or is there some other magic annotation I can apply to get this to properly deserialise these structures into usable DTOs? What will work to load these variant types correctly into a (mostly) statically typed DTO?